# sorting documents by distance from city to city on the roads (not geo) on the sphinx

Tags: sorting, sphinx

I have an interesting problem.

Given:

- "My city"
- List of Documents
- the list of cities and distances between them

I need to sort the documents by their distance from my city in ascending order.

For Example:

- I am in cityX
- I have around the following cities:
  CityA - 50, CityB - 350, CityC - 10, CityD - 321

I have docs: Doc1 - CityA, Doc2 - CityD, Doc3 - CityB, Doc4 - CityX, Doc5 - CityC

I need to get docs in next sorting:

Doc5,
Doc1,
Doc2, 
Doc3

Originally I was going to solve the problem as follows:

create a sorter 
*if (cityid = 945,5, if (cityid = 2050,4, if (cityid = 652,3, if (cityid = 2654,2, if (cityid = 734,1,0))))) as sorter_cityid0*

and then sort it.

like all looks good.

But when it comes to the real problem, the nesting conditions becomes very large and there is an error

**parser stack overflow NEAR**

OK, try not to break a few sorters:

*if (cityid = 945,5, if (cityid = 2050,4, if (cityid = 652,3, if (cityid = 2654,2, if (cityid = 734,1,0))))) as sorter_cityid0, if (cityid = 4372,5, if (cityid = 1123,4, if (cityid = 2657,3, if (cityid = 2655,2, if (cityid = 2052,1,0))))) as sorter_cityid1, if ( cityid = 790,5, if (cityid = 4373,4, if (cityid = 663,3, if (cityid = 475,2, if (cityid = 2651,1,0))))) as sorter_cityid2, if (cityid = 403,5, if (cityid = 1200,4, if (cityid = 855,3, if (cityid = 2669,2, if (cityid = 785,1,0))))) as sorter_cityid3 ....*

But then there is a new restriction

**too many sort-by attributes; maximum count is 5**

In the examples, I do not specify a full embedding

*And the question is: Have you encountered this problem and how to solve?*

Considered for each city separately, and when pagination consider what the city was and calculate what city I have to show on the page?

for example: page 1 - a city of 1.2

Page 25 -
I think that was on the first page, how many documents, if you run out of the city - go to the next town, and so, until we reach our page ...

P.S.

**geosearch not suitable because the distance is used on roads, rather than the coordinates**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using the SphinxAPI (rather than SphinxQL) would recommend the `SetOverride` method. That was able to cope with long lists.

For SphinxQL, there is the `REMAP()` function
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#misc-functions
but I dont know how many values it can cope with.

The most 'scalable' solution, is possibly to reformat the data into a JSON attribute, can then just sort on that directly. But that will probably take some extensive coding.

Comment: Thank You
I tried version 2.1.9 and I have "something went wrong", and the last - all ok. Apparently, the problem is in the client and I will explore this point further.
If interested, the error was "sort-by attribute not fund" and "unknown attribute name in outgoing"
Although the same request to 2.2.7 have been a great success

Comment: I'm going to try today or tomorrow! But such a moment: the method takes the values as docId-newValue. But I do not know what DocID I need to change =) It looks like  that I need to take the maximum number of documents and then sort them after? But then the Sphinx is no longer needed to do it :)

Comment: I dont think the REMAP function is limited to working on the DocID. Otherwise would recommend the JSON attribute solution.

Comment: yes, REMAP is good thing. I will try it in real life. But I need to update sphinx from 2.1.9 to edge (problems with encodings now :( )

Comment: Have you try to use REMAP for sphinxAPI (SetSelect) ? I have error **select: syntax error, unexpected ',' near ',2050,652), (0,1,2) ) as rmp1** (SetSelect was : _*,REMAP(cityid,  sorter, (945,2050,652), (0,1,2) ) as rmp1_). Strange, because _REMAP(cityid,  sorter, (0), (0) ) as rmp1_ works.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of cities is small and/or fixed, you could add one column for the pre-computed distance from the current document to each other city. Then just select the correct column when sorting.